# iPhone : How to implement android AlertDialog like functionality?

Tags: ios, objective-c, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement functionality in iphone to show Table in AlertView and on click of Table it Fills some control on parent view.

In Android we can do this Through AlertDialog but IN Iphone I googled but did not find some suggestion to implement this thing.

Below is Android code, but how to do this through IOS

```
   new AlertDialog.Builder(MakeReservation.this).setTitle("Previous Locations").setItems(locArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      String str = locArray[which];
      if (str.contains(",")) {
       String[] Address = str.split(",");
       // String[] PickAddress = "Snoufer School, Gaithersburg, MD 45123".split(",");
       if (Address.length > 0)
        pickUpStreet.setText(Address[0]);

         for (int i = 0; i < getResources().getStringArray(R.array.state_symbols).length; i++)
          if (getResources().getStringArray(R.array.state_symbols)[i].equals(getStateCity[0])) {
           pos = i;
           break;
          }

         pickUpState.setSelection(pos);
        }
        if (getStateCity.length > 1)
         pickUpZip.setText(getStateCity[1]);
       }

      }
     }
    }).create().show();
```

Comment: First read about the delegate pattern. Then implement one of the [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how it shows in android the alert-dialog u seeks.
But I guess you are searching for something like this [Image1](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-tableview-in-a.html) [Image2](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/custom-uialertview-with-uitableview/).

[image: UITableView with Section-Header inside UIAlertView]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Swift :** Have a look at my code:

What you need a uipickerview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var gradeTextField: UITextField!

    var gradePicker: UIPickerView!
    let gradePickerValues = ["5. Klasse", "6. Klasse", "7. Klasse"]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return gradePickerValues.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return gradePickerValues[row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        gradeTextField.text = gradePickerValues[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        gradePicker = UIPickerView()
        gradePicker.dataSource = self
        gradePicker.delegate = self
        gradeTextField.inputView = gradePicker
        gradeTextField.text = gradePickerValues[0]
    }
}
```